# JSON to POJO conversion using Jackson & JsonPath

Tags: json, jackson, unmarshalling, pojo, jsonpath

I have a data scenario, where I want to populate an attribute in my POJO class using the attribute of a nested object. The below is just an example, but I have many such nested variables.

For example my java class is as follow

```
public class Book{
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private  String isbn;
    ...     
}
```

And my json response that I need to deserialize is as follow

```
{
    "title":"the jungle book",
    "author":"Rudyard Kipling",
    "code":{
        "isbn":"1616416920"
        }
 }
```

So the attribute **isbn** in my java class, needs to be populated using the nested field **isbn** inside  the **code** object.

I tried to use the **@JsonProperty** as follow

```
@JsonProperty(value="code.isbn")
private String isbn;
```

But it still set the attribute **isbn** to null inside my java POJO class.
Can someone please suggest how can I do this.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: is there any regularity or consistency in the json structure? are th nested properties under `"code"`?

Comment: In my actual scenario, which I cannot share due to PHI, there are multiple such attributes which are at different levels. Creating and instantiating so many classes that I may not use will lead to waste of memory, hence I am trying to find a way, where I can pull such nested attributes into my POJO object using JsonPath. I was preferring if I can use ObjectMapper class to parse my JSOn to POJO and use JsonPath in some way to fetch the nested attributes (like isbn in the example I shared above)

Answer (score 0):

you can write custom code to parse the json to create Book object having isbn value set by parsing nested object.

or

for the given json, you need to define an object say "Code"

```
public class Book {
    @JsonProperty(value="title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty(value="author")
    private String author;

    @JsonProperty(value="code")
    private Code code;
}

public class Code {
    @JsonProperty(value="isbn")
    public String isbn;
}
```